# why does winsock recv sometimes return less than the requested data

Tags: delphi, winsock

When I receive data from the target, E.G.:

```
function TSlave.RecvInteger:integer;
var
  p:pointer;
  len, i, sent:integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  len := 4;
  p := @result;
  sent := 0;
  repeat
    Sleep(10);
    i := Recv(Sk, p^, len, 0);
    if i <= 0 then begin
      Result := -1;
      break;
    end;
    inc(sent, i);
    dec(len, i);
    p :=ptr(integer(@result) + sent);
  until len = 0;
end;
```

I have to do that just to get a perfect result, why is there sometimes packet loss when you call recv?

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code so that it's readable. If that is in fact the way your real code is formatted, then please do yourself a favor and read the first sentence of this comment again. :-) Also, it's just clutter when you include commented out code in your questions, as it has no relevance to your question. (If it did, it wouldn't be commented out in the first place.) Thanks.

Comment: KenWhite, i'll work on learning to properly format my code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no packet loss, the packets just haven't been received yet. If you haven't gotten all the data you want or expect, just call receive again. Protocols like TCP (which I presume is what you are using) have no way to "glue bytes together" nor do they provide application-level messages. If you want to do that, you need to write code to do it.

If receive never returned fewer than the bytes you asked for, it would be almost impossible to use if you didn't know exactly how many bytes you were expecting. That would be pretty awful.

If you *do* know exactly how many bytes you are expecting, just keep calling the receive function until you receive that many. That sounds like your situation, so just write your own receive function that keeps calling the low-level receive function until it has accumulated the specified number of bytes. (That's not the best way to do it, but that will work.)

Comment: also, I recently found an exploit that I had to fix(caused the server to go to 100% cpu usage), does receive ever return 0?I am always sending 1+ data to the server, so would it return 0 ever?

Comment: If receive returns zero, that indicates a normal shutdown of the connection.